# What are the precedence levels of the Swift operators?

Tags: swift

I want to look up the precedence levels of some operators. Is there a list of them all somewhere? I haven't found one.

Comment: I vote to reopen, as this is very necessary in Swift custom-operator programming, yet hard to find an authoritative source

Answer (score 12):

> Updated for Swift 3.0

#### Swift 3.0

There is now a [page](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/operator_declarations) in the Swift docs.

All the precedence groups are listed below (also visible Command clicking `import Swift`):

```
precedencegroup BitwiseShiftPrecedence {
    higherThan: MultiplicationPrecedence
}

precedencegroup FunctionArrowPrecedence {
    associativity: right
}

precedencegroup AssignmentPrecedence {
    associativity: right
    assignment: true
    higherThan: FunctionArrowPrecedence
}

precedencegroup RangeFormationPrecedence {
    higherThan: CastingPrecedence
}

precedencegroup CastingPrecedence {
    higherThan: NilCoalescingPrecedence
}

precedencegroup AdditionPrecedence {
    associativity: left
    higherThan: RangeFormationPrecedence
}

precedencegroup NilCoalescingPrecedence {
    associativity: right
    higherThan: ComparisonPrecedence
}

precedencegroup ComparisonPrecedence {
    higherThan: LogicalConjunctionPrecedence
}

precedencegroup LogicalConjunctionPrecedence {
    associativity: left
    higherThan: LogicalDisjunctionPrecedence
}

precedencegroup LogicalDisjunctionPrecedence {
    associativity: left
    higherThan: TernaryPrecedence
}

precedencegroup DefaultPrecedence {
    higherThan: TernaryPrecedence
}

precedencegroup TernaryPrecedence {
    associativity: right
    higherThan: AssignmentPrecedence
}

precedencegroup MultiplicationPrecedence {
    associativity: left
    higherThan: AdditionPrecedence
}
```

#### Swift 2.1

In the Swift header:

```
infix operator %= {
    associativity right
    precedence 90
    assignment
}

infix operator >= {
    associativity none
    precedence 130
}

infix operator != {
    associativity none
    precedence 130
}

infix operator <<= {
    associativity right
    precedence 90
    assignment
}

infix operator || {
    associativity left
    precedence 110
}

infix operator += {
    associativity right
    precedence 90
    assignment
}

infix operator / {
    associativity left
    precedence 150
}

infix operator - {
    associativity left
    precedence 140
}

infix operator << {
    associativity none
    precedence 160
}

infix operator |= {
    associativity right
    precedence 90
    assignment
}

infix operator >>= {
    associativity right
    precedence 90
    assignment
}

infix operator <= {
    associativity none
    precedence 130
}

infix operator -= {
    associativity right
    precedence 90
    assignment
}

infix operator ?? {
    associativity right
    precedence 131
}

infix operator > {
    associativity none
    precedence 130
}

infix operator ~= {
    associativity none
    precedence 130
}

infix operator + {
    associativity left
    precedence 140
}

infix operator ^ {
    associativity left
    precedence 140
}

infix operator ... {
    associativity none
    precedence 135
}

infix operator /= {
    associativity right
    precedence 90
    assignment
}

infix operator * {
    associativity left
    precedence 150
}

infix operator *= {
    associativity right
    precedence 90
    assignment
}

infix operator & {
    associativity left
    precedence 150
}

infix operator !== {
    associativity none
    precedence 130
}

infix operator % {
    associativity left
    precedence 150
}

infix operator && {
    associativity left
    precedence 120
}

infix operator &* {
    associativity left
    precedence 150
}

infix operator &+ {
    associativity left
    precedence 140
}

infix operator &= {
    associativity right
    precedence 90
    assignment
}

infix operator >> {
    associativity none
    precedence 160
}

infix operator &- {
    associativity left
    precedence 140
}

infix operator === {
    associativity none
    precedence 130
}

infix operator ~> {
    associativity left
    precedence 255
}

infix operator ..< {
    associativity none
    precedence 135
}

infix operator < {
    associativity none
    precedence 130
}

infix operator == {
    associativity none
    precedence 130
}

infix operator ^= {
    associativity right
    precedence 90
    assignment
}

infix operator | {
    associativity left
    precedence 140
}
```

Comment: Thank you! What does the associativity part mean?

Comment: See the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AdvancedOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH27-ID41)

Comment: @whoKnows yeah it doesn't. Its probably not a proper operator per se. I'd probably say its high than all the above operators, though if you're unsure use brackets or separate statements!

Comment: where did you get the information, i.e., your source?

Comment: @lmiguelvargasf see [matts answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28328739/849645) below.

Comment: Your link to the Swift docs is a 404. Did it go here? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/operator_declarations

Comment: what about the comma operator? like in `if let high = high, price > high || self.high == nil ` does the `||` have lower precedence than the comma?

Comment: @johnbakers I don't believe the comma when used liked that is an operator, more todo with syntax - `if (let high = high, price > high) || (self.high == nil)` wouldn't be valid. It's use in this case in an explicit `AND` (`&&`) where all expressions must be `true` or, in the case of `let`s, successful unwrapped optionals.

Answer (score 11):

1. At the top of your code, where the `import` statement is, add a new line:

   ```
   import Swift
   ```
2. Command-click "Swift".

   Whoa, what's this? It's the Swift header file! All of Swift is here - including all the operators and their precedence settings.
3. Read and learn.